# iOS Safari isn't playing Spotify preview_url

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, spotify, howler.js

I've built a microsite, that play random songs with Spotify. On desktop-browsers, there is no problem - I play the preview_urls - perfect! But on iPhone (iOS), the preview_url has no response - my player isn't play the preview. Looks like Safari couldn't load the song.

I've built the player with howler.js.

http://glui.me/?i=q229w7c61iyb02c/2014-06-30_at_17.23.png/

Anyone same problem with Spotify and iOS/Safari? Anyone an idea whats going wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio is locked on iOS until a sound is played within a user interaction (like a 'touchstart' event). v1.1.22 of howler.js has implemented a new feature that will try to automatically unlock the audio, but depending on your UI setup it may be a good idea to show an overlay of some sort that requires the user to touch the screen before they can use the app, thus unlocking the audio.

The howler.js docs have been updated explaining this: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#ios-playback